# Existence of a twice differentiable curve on a manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Given $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ a differentiable manifold and a tangent vector $v$ at a given point $x\in S$. Question: Is there a curve $\eta:[0,\epsilon)\to S$ starting at $x$ with tangent $v$ such that $\eta$ is twice differentiable at $0$?

Comment: It depends on what amount of differentiability you assume for the manifold $S$. If $S$ is a $C^k$-differentiable manifold then there is such a $C^k$-curve $\eta$, as you can easily see in local coordinates at $x$.

Comment: The manifold $S$ is given by the set of zeros of a smooth function $H:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ with locally constant rank jacobian.

Comment: @Shake: What do you mean by a smooth function (how many derivatives)? If you mean infinitely differentiable, then the answer is trivial. If you mean a function that is merely $C^1$ then it becomes interesting. 

Comment: @Lee: $S$ in in $\mathbb R^n$ so we can talk about differentiability of the curve of any order regardless of what $S$ is. 

Comment: @Ryan: Yes, I was just pointing out a special case, given that the OP did not specify the level of differentiability of $S$. In some contexts, to say that $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is differentiable means that it is $C^\infty$ differentiable, and I was unsure whether the OP knew that.

Comment: It would certainly allay confusion if Shake would specify the level of differentiability, as suggested by Misha's comment.

Comment: $H$ is a $C^2$ function. Does this mean that $S$ is a $C^2$-differentiable manifold? What does it mean that the question is trivial? Are all tangent curves C^2? How do I see that?

I'm not very familiar to differential geometry, as you may notice.

Comment: Correction: $H:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ with no relation between $m$ and $n$.

Comment: You should really edit your question rather than continually making revisions in the comments. 

Answer (score 1):

From the comment of the OP, $H:\mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^m$ is $C^\infty$ and has constant rank Jacobian.
Thus $S=H^{-1}(0)$ is a $C^\infty$ manifold of codimension the rank of the Jacobian; see 1.13
of [(here)](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/dgbook.pdf). Thus such a curve exists (even a $C^\infty$-curve).

Comment: I think the OP suggested $H$ is just $C^2$.  So the pre-image will only be $C^2$. 

Comment: Note that both implicit function theorem and, hence, constant rank theorem, work without reduction in smoothness. Therefore, in OP's case, $S$ is locally a graph of a $C^2$-function and, hence, obviously contains $C^2$-curves tangent to every tangent vector. This (implicit function theorem) is undergraduate level material or 1-st year graduate material depending on the country. All in all, the question is not suitable for MO, math.stackexchange would be the right  place. Voting to close. 